# some question on Buera and Nicolini (2004)

Tags: macroeconomics, theory

I am struggling with understanding one result in [Buera and Nicolini (2004)](http://www.econ.ucla.edu/fjbuera/papers/matFINAL2.pdf) published in JME. In page 538, they write
$$A_t(h^t) b_{t-1}(h^{t-1}) = Z_t(h^{t-1})$$
where $A_t(h^t)$ is a $N \times J$ matrix, $b_{t-1}(h^{t-1})$ is a $J\times 1$ vector, and $Z_t(h^{t-1})$ is a $N\times 1$ vector. $N$ is the number of states and $J$ is the number of maturities. Then, in [page 539](https://www.econ.ucla.edu/fjbuera/papers/matFINAL2.pdf#page=11), they say that

"a necessary condition for the Ramsey to be implementable is that the government can issue non-contingent bonds in at least as many maturities as possible realization of the stock, i.e., $J \ge N$.''

For an ease of notation, write the above equation as $A b = Z$. Suppose that $J > N$. Premultiplying a $J \times N$ matrix $D$,
$$D Ab = D Z$$
If $D$ is an inverse of $A$, rank($DA$) = $J$. But, $\text{rank}(DA) \le \min(\text{rank}(D), \text{rank}(A))\le N$. Contradiction. I think I am missing something important. I would appreciate if someone helps me with this.

Comment: There is something I can't understand. $A$ is a $n\times j$ matrix, if $n\neq j$ $A$ is a non-square matrix, and can't have an inverse, the inverse of a matrix is defined for square matrices only.

Comment: @shk910 Is the whole first part of the question necessary, or could it be reduced to the part starting with "*For an ease of notation*..."?

Comment: @BakerStreet Perhaps it is a [generalized inverse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_inverse)? The article is "*an*", as in "$D$ is an inverse of $A$". In that case rank of $DA$ would be $N \leq J$ though.

Comment: @Giskard  maybe, but nothing can be said without reading the paper, it sholuld be specified.

Comment: @Giskard The pseudo inverse  also is unique,  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moore%E2%80%93Penrose_inverse, so it is difficult to say without more information what the paper of Buera and Nicolini is talking about.

Comment: Is this $D$ still in the paper though? I thought the papers part stops at the quotation marks at the middle.

Comment: @BakerStreet Here is the relevant page, in case you are interested http://www.econ.ucla.edu/fjbuera/papers/matFINAL2.pdf#page=12